# Scissors analogue?

Tags: software-recommendation

In Windows 7, there is one very handy tool called "Scissors".

I use it to capture part of the screen, one window or the whole desktop.

It also has simple painting tools which are very useful - I can make a screenshot and mark some things on it with brush or colour marker.

Is there any analogue of this tool on Ubuntu?

I know Ubuntu has a tool that can capture a rectangle on screen and save as image but I cannot choose file format and I cannot add any marks on it, and have to open it in external editor and that is very inconvenient.

Answer (score 10):

I downloaded a programme called Shutter from the Software Center

[image]

This gives you 20 or so ways to select and catch various windows and menus it also allows you to annotate your image see the second screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more tool available in Ubuntu for both screenshot and paint purposes named as 
GNUpaint. You can install it in your PC with

```
sudo apt-get install gpaint
```

After that, open it from Unity dash by typing GNUpaint.

It looks like this: [image]